# Combinatorial identity in deriving expected absolute sum of Rademacher RV

Tags: expected-value, random-walk, random

I was studying on getting the bound for the expectation of absolute sum of Rademacher RV.
Please refer the following link.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html.

I encountered the following expression.

$$\sum_{d=1}^{J}\frac{d}{(J+d)!(J-d)!}
= \frac{1}{2J!(J-1)!}$$

for any natural number $J$.
It would be greatly appreciated if anybody can help me derive the identity in the above link.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you for your comment Santos. Just fix the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the sum on the left. We have
$$(2J)!S=\sum_{d=1}^J\frac{d(2J)!}{(J+d)!(J-d)!}=\sum_{d=1}^J d\binom{2J}{J-d}=\sum_{i=0}^{J-1}(J-i)\binom{2J}i.$$
where we have substituted $d=J-i$. We now claim that
$$\sum_{i=0}^r (J-i)\binom{2J}i=\frac{r+1}2\binom{2J}{r+1}.$$
We'll show this by induction; for the base case of $r=0$, both sides are $J$. For the inductive step,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{r+1}(J-i)\binom{2J}i=\sum_{i=0}^r(J-i)\binom{2J}i+(J-r-1)\binom{2J}{r+1}=\frac{2J-r-1}2\binom{2J}{r+1},$$
which equals the desired quantity by comparing ratios of consecutive binomial coefficients. So, applying this at $r=J-1$,
$$S=\frac1{(2J)!}\cdot\frac{J}2\binom{2J}J=\frac1{2(J!)(J-1)!},$$
as desired.